# Breaking down liquid malt extract

Tags: lme

I've been brewing 2 gal batches of beer from extracts like Mr Beer. Their LME packets are only 8.8 oz. Can I take a 3.3 lb. can, dilute it with a sufficient amount of water and divide it up into 6 containers to use at a later time? How long can it keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't dilute the extract, for a couple reasons:

First, the extract doesn't need to be sterile when stored, because it contains so little water. Add some water and things will start growing.

Second, if your water contains any kind of chlorine, it will probably break down and ruin the flavor of the extract.

What you can do is heat the stuff up to make it thinner, repackage that for later.

I also don't think you should store it cold. If the sugars crystalize, then the excess water becomes available to spoil the rest of the extract (that's what happens to honey: been there, smelled it, made mead anyway).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can split it up, how long it keeps is depending on how you store it, and at what temperature.

I really don't know how long you can store it, but your best bet for it to keep longer is in the freezer. next best fridge.

also you may need to recalculate how much you need per 2 gals, since mr beer may use a different kind then what you have.